# How to display intent chooser when long click listview item?

Tags: android, android-intent, contextmenu

I have a list view that contains some data, I want to share it by through [intent chooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

I found long click on a listview item will trigger context menu event, and the common way to use a context menu is the build a menu in **onCreateContextMenu()** and then get line index from menuInfo in **onContextItemSelected()**. But in my case I want to display intent chooser directly when when I long click the list view item.

Do I make myself understood? How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```